# Can sendmail include an attachment?

Tags: centos, email, sendmail

Is it possible to include an attachment with sendmail? I am generating the following `emailfile.eml` files with the following layout

```
From: Company Name <mycompany@example.com>
To: recipient@example.com
CC: someoneelse@example.com
Subject: Generated Output

Mime-Version: 1.0

This will be the body copy even though it's terrible
```

I am sending these emails using

```
# /usr/sbin/sendmail -t < emailfile.eml
```

This part is working file but I would like to include an attachment to this email.

Comment: Use `uuencode` or `mutt`.

Comment: I was hoping to use something more like Content-Disposition: attachment but I can't get it to work

Comment: Do you want some text AND attachment OR attachment only? ["attachment only" case is trivial ]

Comment: I'd like to send body copy and the attachment, preferably using sendmail and the eml file with Content-Disposition

Comment: In such case the most simple is to use email client e.g. mutt

Comment: You *may* have a `mailx` implementation that supports attachments with `-A`...

Comment: Answers go in answers, not in questions.

Comment: JdeBP is right one sec, I will correct it

Comment: There all fixed

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Posting the solution that worked for me in case it can help anyone else, sorry it's so late.

The most reliable way I found for doing this was to include the attachment as base64 in the eml file itself, bellow is an example of the eml contents.

Note 01 : the base64 for the file comes from running the base64 command on linux using the attachment as an argument (should work with any base64 tool)

Note 02 : the string used for the boundary is just nonsense using the date and random upper case letters

Filename : emlfile.eml

```
From: Sender <sender@email.co.za>
To: recipient01@email.co.za
CC: recipient02@email.co.za
Disposition-Notification-To: recipient01@email.co.za
Subject: Generic Subject
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="19032019ABCDE"

--19032019ABCDE
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="US-ASCII"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: inline

Generic Body Copy

--19032019ABCDE
Content-Type: application;
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="MyPdfAttachment.pdf"

*base64 string goes here (no asterix)*

--19032019ABCDE--
```

Then the filename.eml file can be sent using the command and it will include the attachment

```
# /usr/sbin/sendmail -t < filename.eml
```

Comment: Great answer and completely correct. Also, for multiple attachments you can repeat the section from the second-to-last line upward to the second-to-last delimiter (inclusive) as many times as needed within the .eml file.

Comment: Thank you very much! <3

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thanks!

Comment: You're very welcome!

Comment: How do you put bash commands in eml file? Like echo $something

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for to send a report of daily server activities 

Comment: An example of the bash code would be useful. I tried and all I have is an email with a base64 encoded string inside the body.

Answer (score 17):

With `mutt` you can simply use:

```
echo "This is the message body" | mutt -a "/path/to/file_to_attach" -s "subject of message" -- recipient@domain.com
```

Using `mail` command:

```
mail -a /opt/emailfile.eml -s "Email File" user@example.com < /dev/null
```

`-a` is used for attachments.

You can use `SendEmail`:

```
sendemail -t to@example.com -m "Here is the file." -a attachmentFile
```

Comment: `SendEmail` is for Ubuntu, so not sure if it will work for CentOS or not.

Comment: Yeah, I don't have `sendemail` on my workplace's CentOS, we just have `sendmail`.

Comment: on my ubuntu system, the `mail` option was `-A` not `-a`

Comment: Does it allow to specify a custom From address?